# How can I host my ruby rdoc documentation on rdoc.info website?

Tags: ruby

I have made a Ruby gem recently now I want to make a documentation for that gem using `rdoc` now I have installed the rdoc gem in my project and ran the following command on the windows CMD.

`rdoc`

this created a doc folder on my project now how can I push this doc folder on rdoc.info website so that my documentation gets displayed there. I looked on the official `rdoc` documentation but did not found any source how to push your docs on the website. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a public GitHub repo or public Gem published on [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org)?

Comment: When you push a gem to RubyGems, the docs should be auto-generated and linked from it's page there

Comment: @maxpleaner The doc do auto generating it but I have a new issue now that is
my new edits are not getting saved

Comment: @tadman I have a public GitHub repo and I did published my gem on ruby gems.org but the when I make new changes its not updating over there I mean on the ruby docs.info website

Comment: Do I need to push the gem on ruby gems.org to update the document on the website ?

Edit: My GitHub repo is full up-to-date with the ruby project on the local server but when I make changes on the files I mean when I make comments it does not appears on the website (Ruby doc.info)

Comment: Yeah, the docs are only generated when you push a new gem version to rubygems.

Comment: Btw @maxpleaner sorry for the disturbance again why does it takes time after I change the version of the gem to update the document ? I mean after lot of refreshing the page then I can see the update otherwise it it says cant find document for the following version. 

Also if I share my documentation link to my users will they get to see the changes with that link even after I update something or I have to provide the new link to them 

Please clarify me about this both query. Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you link them to the doc page _without_ the version as part of the URL (e.g. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/byebug/) it will use the latest version available. As to why it takes a whle to update - I have noticed this, and I think it just has to do with how rubygems.org works ... most likely they generate all the docs in background jobs, and it just takes time to go through the queue ...

Comment: @maxpleaner Okay previously mistakenly I made a project on that website for the other version called `0.1.3` now as you said that using that sort of link will get the user the updated now when I use that sort of link I get the project for version 0.1.3 not the current version which is 0.1.5 now how can I delete that version project ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're worrying so much about this. Just link people to rubydoc.info/gems/my_gem and it will probably be fine. Most of the time people aren't going to look at it right after an update anyway. And even if they do, they might still have an old version of the gem installed. You can use `gem yank` to remove old versions from RubyGems but that isn't meant for this purpose.